# Why digital signature image doesn't display with correct scaled in Android web view?

Tags: android-webview

I am developing an web view app in Android. It provides a HTML5 form which contains a signature pad input that is actually a HTML canvas and after user submits the form the signature will be captured and saved as base64 image format: [[Picture: sign to a canvas]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfR7b.jpg).

But when submit and reload the form the signature isn't displayed correctly to the web view, it looks like to be scaled down in both width and height dimensions: [[Picture: Display image in web view]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoQAD.jpg)

The signature is a image with src is a base64 encoded string:

```
<img class="signature" src="data:image/png;base64,....==">
```

Please note that this signature is displayed correctly in a Chrome browser.

Could anyone knows why the signature isn't displayed correctly on Android web view?

Thanks in advance